# Executing Gstreamer pipeline script within php code

Tags: php, shell, gstreamer, pipeline

I have a written an script for gstreamer application (pipeline) in ubuntu to capture 2 video streams via webcam and a frame grabber and put them into one container:

```
 gst-launch -e mpegtsmux name="muxer" ! filesink location=TestHDMainCamera.ts \
 v4l2src device="/dev/video1" ! video/x-raw-yuv,  width=1280 ,height=720, \
  framerate=30/1  ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! muxer. \
 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1024 ,height=768, \
 framerate=30/1 ! x264enc !  muxer.  pulsesrc \
 device="alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_AAF8A63E-02-C930e.analog-stereo" \
  ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc target=1 cbr=true  ! muxer.
```

I just put it into a .sh file and execute it via terminal. to make life easier I wrote a simple php code to create a simple(!) website interface (running on local host)  to control the capturing process (start: run the .sh file and stop: Ctrl+c)

including two extra buttons to just test the streams coming from frame grabber and webcam separately to see if they are connected or not:

Test Preview of webcam:

```
  gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

Test Preview of FrameGrabber:

```
  gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

Here is the question:

Every time I load the page and I press the start button it seems that php executes the .sh pipeline and terminates it immediately (I get this message on the screen: Freeing pipeline ...) therefor I get no captured stream(!)  even if I try to use the test buttons to just have a live stream result is the same...

can you please help me and tell me how can I run the pipeline code for gstreamer to capture using this php code? (gstreamer pipeline needs to be terminated only when I press "stop" button which should perform the Ctrl+c function)

More info:

Here is the main.php code for the interface (it's a little bit messy, sorry about that):

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
echo '<p>Hello</p>';
print_r($_GET);

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case 'Test Webcam':
        testWebcam();
        break;
    case 'Test Framegrabber':
        testFramegrabber();
        break;
}
}

function testFramegrabber() {
echo "The Test Framegrabber function is called.";
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}

function testWebcam() {
echo "The Test Webcam function is called.";
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}

//$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
//echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
<form action="main.php">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="action" value="Test Webcam" />
<input type="submit" class="button" name="action" value="Test     Framegrabber" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the record.php for the buttons and other details:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Recording page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
var w = null; // initialize variable

//function to start the timer
function startTimer()
{
// First check whether Web Workers are supported
if (typeof(Worker)!=="undefined"){
   // Check whether Web Worker has been created. If not, create a new Web     Worker based on the Javascript file simple-timer.js
   if (w==null){
      w = new Worker("simple-timer.js");
   }
   // Update timer div with output from Web Worker
   w.onmessage = function (event) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = event.data;
   };
} else {
   // Web workers are not supported by your browser
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does     not support Web Workers ...";
}
}

//function to stop the timer
function stopTimer()
{
w.terminate();
timerStart = true;
w = null;
}

function handleTimer() {
    document.getElementById("timerp").innerHTML = "start timer";
}
</script>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php
 echo '<p>Hello</p>';
 print_r($_GET);

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'Test Webcam':
            testWebcam();
            break;
        case 'Test Framegrabber':
            testFramegrabber();
            break;
        case 'Record':
            record();
            break;
     }
}

function testFramegrabber() {
    echo "The Test Framegrabber function is called.";
    $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}

function testWebcam() {
    echo "The Test Webcam function is called.";
    $output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
 }

function record(){
echo "The Record function is called.";
echo "<script> startTimer(); </script>";
}
 function stop(){
    echo "The Stop function is called.";
    echo "<script> stopTimer(); </script>";
}
//$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
//echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
 <div class="header">A simple timer:</div>

   <div class="timer" id="timer">00:00</div>
   <div class="buttons">
      <button onclick="startTimer()" id="button1">Start</button>
      <button onclick="stopTimer()" id = "button2">Stop</button>
   </div>
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="record.php">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Sreen recorder</legend>

 <table class="tg" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e">fdsfs</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="recordbtn"></label>
        <div class="controls">
        <button id="recordbtn" name="action" class="btn btn-danger"     value="Record" onclick="startTimer()">Record</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-031e">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="stopbtn"></label>
        <div class="controls">
        <button id="stopbtn" name="action" class="btn btn-inverse"     value="Stop" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
     <td class="tg-031e">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="nextbtn"></label>
        <div class="controls">
        <button id="nextbtn" name="action" class="btn btn-inverse">Next     recording</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="webcamTest"></label>
<div class="controls">
<button id="webcamTest" name="action" value="Test Webcam" class="btn     btn-info">Test Webcam</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="testFramegrabber"></label>
<div class="controls">
<button id="testFramegrabber" name="action" value="Test Framegrabber"     class="btn btn-info">Test Framegrabber</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="recordPath">Path to record</label>
<div class="controls">
<select id="recordPath" name="recordPath" class="input-xlarge">
<option>/desktop</option>
<option>/home/var</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>



</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and just a simple timer to be shown while capturing on the page:

```
    var timerStart = true;

function myTimer(d0)
{
   // get current time
   var d=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // calculate time difference between now and initial time
   var diff = d-d0;
   // calculate number of minutes
   var minutes = Math.floor(diff/1000/60);
   // calculate number of seconds
   var seconds = Math.floor(diff/1000)-minutes*60;
   var myVar = null;
   // if number of minutes less than 10, add a leading "0"
   minutes = minutes.toString();
   if (minutes.length == 1){
      minutes = "0"+minutes;
   }
   // if number of seconds less than 10, add a leading "0"
   seconds = seconds.toString();
   if (seconds.length == 1){
      seconds = "0"+seconds;
   }

   // return output to Web Worker
   postMessage(minutes+":"+seconds);
}

if (timerStart){
   // get current time
   var d0=(new Date()).valueOf();
   // repeat myTimer(d0) every 100 ms
   myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer(d0)},100);
   // timer should not start anymore since it has been started
   timerStart = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking your apache user.
You say you are using ubuntu, so it would be "www-data", which probably can't access either your DISPLAY or "/dev/video0".

- Try to execute you .sh as www-data in a terminal (you might need to enable shell access to www-data at /etc/passwd)
- One quick and dirty solution would be running your php as a normal user. From a terminal write:

  php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t your_directory/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I couldn't start the GStreamer pipeline from the PHP code. But I was able to start in the terminal.

The Solution for me was I had to use 'SUDO' before the command. As I was running the PHP Code on the Apache server. The apache server runs on the www-data user and that needs SUDO access to run the commands.

I was using:(in PHP)

```
    $start = shell_exec('usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=(int)1920,height=(int)1080" ! nvvidconv ! "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)I420" ! omxh264enc bitrate=3000000 ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://127.0.0.1:1936/mycamera/mystream" 2>&1 &');

        echo "<pre>$start</pre>";
```

But I had to use SUDO as below with 'sudo': (in PHP)

```
    $start = shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=(int)1920,height=(int)1080" ! nvvidconv ! "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=(string)I420" ! omxh264enc bitrate=3000000 ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://127.0.0.1:1936/webcam/mystream" 2>&1 &');

        echo "<pre>$start</pre>";
```